# view can not response longclick after animations

Tags: android, animation, long-press

[image]

as above showes, a LinearLayout container has 4 child views. longpressing on any child view and drag it to top of another view, they will swap position(after dropping) with animation(TranslateAnimation).

if draging back and forth quickly(view swaping animation are executed quickly), after dropping, some views just can not accept longpressing(isLongclickabl() returns true)

if I change the swapping animation duration from 300ms to 100ms, quick swapping won't lead to longpressing "disabled"

what is the reason?

Comment: please post your code here.....